# Find the minimum difference between two arrays

Tags: algorithm

Given two sorted arrays, A and B, find i,j for which |A[i] - B[j]| is minimum.

Comment: Please, phrase what you would like to know as a question!

Comment: Given 2 homework questions, you have to ... at least try them yourself.

Comment: He wants to know the most efficient way to find the smallest distance between any two items in the two different arrays.

Comment: It makes a difference if they are sorted in ascending or descending order.  Which is it?

Comment: Why the haste to close? This *is* a real question. It is *not* vague, incomplete, overly broad or rhetorical. It *can* be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: @marcog: If for no other reason than to hopefully discourage him from his current spree of copying questions from some textbook into SO.

Comment: @David There are 4 more questions from this poster (all closed) in a record time of 9 mins!

Comment: @David,belisarius, Why can't I ask 4 questions in 9 minutes? After a round of interviews, I wanted to post questions which I got. Do I really have to post MY answers with MY question, in order for them to look legitimate?

Comment: @David, these questions are not copied from any textbook. I have given an explanation above.

Comment: @dharm0us, "Do I really have to post MY answers with MY question" for homework and interview questions that would be a good start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the arrays are sorted, you can pass through them with 2 pointers (one for each array). If `|A[i+1] - B[j]| < |A[i] - B[j+1]|` then increment `i`, otherwise increment `j`. Continue until you've reached the end of one of the arrays. Keep track of the minimal indexes as you go.

Comment: what's the worst case run time complexity of this code ?  It should be n^2, no ?

Comment: O(nlogm): 

for each element in A, use Binary Search method to find the element with the closest value in array B.

Comment: How do I figure out answers like this myself? What was the method you used to solve it?

Comment: what if |A[0]- B[0]| is less than all the other differences. May be you should add corner case to compare first two elements of arrays too, other than that it looks good to me.